# Integrating Apache Wicket with Jython

Tags: wicket, jython

I am new to web development, but quite familiar with both Java and Python. In my beginning experiments with web development using Java, I discovered Apache Wicket; around the same time I also discovered Jython (v 2.5). I am wondering if there's a way to integrate Wicket and Jython so I can write Jython scripts instead of Java classes to use Wicket. So far I haven't been able to do that.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apache Wicket, but did you derive your Jython classes from `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: @larsmans: I derived my Jython class from org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication, which obviously finally subclasses java.lang.Object -- it is a Java class. I don't think that's the problem; the problem seems to be that I can't convert my Jython source (.py) files into .class files reflecting the class hierarchy that Wicket expects. When I compile my class (using PythonInterpreter, as mentioned in JSR 223), I get a class with a $py suffix (eg. HelloWorldApplication$py.class), but on introspection, I don't see my classes, I see something that PythonInterpreter produced.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.
There are many people using Wicket successfully with Scala language. It should be the same with Jython, JRuby, Closure, ...
See https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.5-parent/scala-extensions-parent for example with Scala.

Comment: I wasn't able to find pertinent information about using Jython by looking at the project you mentioned -- maybe I looked in the wrong place. It seems to me that there's something called "wicket extensions" that need to be used. The trouble is that even though I can subclass Wicket's Java classes using Jython, I can't get .class files from them reflecting the same class hierarchy -- Jython does something funky there (there's no jythonc utility any more).